# Image won't display but is click-able

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

I try to draw an image over a JDialog that contains a background. What I do is call the class which will draw this image. Here, the "paintComponent" is never called:

```
// class Card
public Card(BufferedImage faceUp, int value) {

    this.faceUp = faceUp;
    this.hide = false;
    this.value = value;
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(Card.this.getX());
            System.out.println("click");
        }

    });

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     System.out.println("here");
    g.drawImage((this.hide) ? Cards.back : this.faceUp, Cards.CARD_WIDTH, Cards.CARD_HEIGHT, this);

}
```

And I call it in my main constructor:

```
public Constructor() {
    initComponent();

    Card c1 = new Card(Cards.cardsContainer.get(1), 1%14); //Image, value

    jPanel1.add(c1);

    c1.setVisible(true);
    c1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    c1.revalidate();
    c1.repaint();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        BufferedImage background_image;

        background_image = ImageIO.read(new File(this.background));
        Graphics2D big = background_image.createGraphics();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        g2.setPaint(new TexturePaint(background_image, rectangle));

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2.fill(rect);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Bataille.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 3) Don't try to load images in the paint methods!  They could be loaded in the constructor and stored as attributes of the class.

Comment: What is the preferred size of Card? What is its actual size in the *rendered* GUI (after `setVisible(true)`)?

Comment: The size of a Card is 86x120 and the JDialog size is set to 800x600 and not resizable.

Comment: Is this the Card size that you think it should be, or the size that debugging the program showed you that it actually is? There's a big difference here, and it's the latter that I've asked you to give to us -- the size of the card in a *rendered* GUI that is supposed to be displaying the card. You may be a bit surprised when you read the results.

Comment: In fact, the displayed size of Card is 0...
@AndrewThompson Ok, no more image loading in `paintComponent`.

Comment: As I suspected. So now you know what you need to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Your Card is showing a size of 0 as I suspected. One thing you can do is give it a preferred size:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  if (Cards.back != null) {
    return new Dimension(Cards.back.getWidth(), Cards.back.getHeight());
  } else {
    return super.getPreferredSize();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried and it didn't work.
In my constructor I put `setSize` and now, it shows the correct size but still won't display.

Answer (score 0):

Oooh my...
The Card was displayed but with the `borderLayout` there was a margin. So I enlarge the panel and it shows up.